# How to get notified when a section of sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout changes in SAPUI5 1.38?

Tags: sapui5

I am working with a SAPUI5 version **1.38** and use in an application the control `sap.uxap.ObjectPageSection` within `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout`. At a certain section, when you click on it, an event should happen.
I haven't found a solution for this yet unfortunately. See:
[image: screenshot]

I have already tried with `attachBrowserEvent` and `addEventDelegate`. But unfortunately, this does not work for this control.

Does anyone have any other ideas how to solve this problem? A workaround?
I would be very grateful for any help.

**View1.controller.js**

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("test123.test123.controller.View1", {
        onInit: function () {
    },
    onAfterRendering: function () {
        var showMessage = function () {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("text");
            return false;
        };

        this.byId("section2").attachBrowserEvent("click", showMessage);
        
        this.byId("section2").addEventDelegate({
          onclick: function () {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("text");
          }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

**View1.view.xml**

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="test123.test123.controller.View1" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:uxap="sap.uxap">
    <App id="idAppControl">
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <uxap:ObjectPageLayout id="ObjectPageLayoutId"
                        useIconTabBar="true"
                        alwaysShowContentHeader="true">
                        <!-- SECTION 1 -->
                        <uxap:sections>
                            <uxap:ObjectPageSection titleUppercase="false" id="section1" title="Section 1">
                                <uxap:subSections>
                                    <uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                                        <uxap:blocks>
                                            <Label text="Content 1" />
                                        </uxap:blocks>
                                    </uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                                </uxap:subSections>
                            </uxap:ObjectPageSection>
                        </uxap:sections>
                        <!-- SECTION 2 -->
                        <uxap:sections >
                            <uxap:ObjectPageSection titleUppercase="false" id="section2" title="Section 2">
                                <uxap:subSections>
                                    <uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                                        <uxap:blocks>
                                            <Label text="Content 2" />
                                        </uxap:blocks>
                                    </uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                                </uxap:subSections>
                            </uxap:ObjectPageSection>
                        </uxap:sections>
                    </uxap:ObjectPageLayout>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: In the [next long-term maintenance version **1.71**](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html), the [`sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout` event **`navigate`**](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout#events/navigate) is available which can help here. Even if 1.38 is still maintained, it's just too outdated to give any meaningful answer. I strongly encourage updating SAPUI5 in your system on a regular basis.

Comment: Hello Boghyon. Thanks for the quick feedback. I already know this event, but unfortunately it is not available in SAPUI5 version 1.38. It is also not possible for me to use a higher version with a customer, therefore the question if there is another possibility / workaround.

Comment: Hey Olga, checkout the documentation of 1.38. There is an event called [`tabSelect`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.58/#docs/api/symbols/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout.html#event:tabSelect).

Comment: @Jan I just noticed it. Someone was faster :) Could you please add your comment as an answer so that olgab can accept it as a solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation of 1.38. There is an event called [`tabSelect`](https://ui5.sap.com/1.38.58/#docs/api/symbols/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout.html#event:tabSelect). The event is comparable to the event `navigate` in 1.40.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can use it as long as the property `useIconTabBar` equals `true`:

```xml
<uxap:ObjectPageLayout tabSelect=".onTabSelect" useIconTabBar="true">
```

---

[1] ⚠️ **BREAKING CHANGE:** with [commit `eb75945`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/eb759459272e57c8c65c50ea9119a3deea36373b) (merged with the 1.40 release), the event **`tabSelect` gets removed in favor of `navigate`**! If the application runs with 1.40 or higher in the future, `tabSelect` should be renamed to [`navigate`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout%23events/navigate) also in your code. But please review the differences between the two events beforehand.